# Wget to download html

Tags: wget

I have been trying to download an html from http://osu.ppy.sh/u/2330158 to get Historical data
but it doesnt download that part. Nor it downloads General, Top Ranks etc

Is there a way to make wget to download it?

Comment: sites that load part of their content via ajax are not so easy to get via wget. you can start using selenium maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That part of the page is loaded dynamically, so wget won't see it as it doesn't support Javascript. However, if you open the web developer tools in your browser of choice and then load the main page you can get the URL which you're really after. For this page, it's: http://osu.ppy.sh/pages/include/profile-history.php?u=2330158&m=0

Luckily, it's another simple, parameterised URL so you can feed that to wget:

```
wget "http://osu.ppy.sh/pages/include/profile-history.php?u=2330158&m=0"
```

That'll get you an html document containing just the historic data you're looking for.

Comment: if his answer is satisfying you should consider accepting the answer and also consider upvoting it.

Comment: Both of those actions would be lovely! :)